# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'Automatisation.DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx'.'

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've been using this [post](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/34037/datagridvewtextboxcell-with-span-behaviour#:%7E:text=For%20successful%20merging%2C%20all%20cells%20of%20the%20region,to%20%282%2C%201%29%20%28see%20screenshot%20at%20the%20top%29.) to replicate the colspan method.

And to make sure the method overrides the default generation of my datagridview, I used the cell formatting function (code down below).

Here's how it goes : when I generate the form and trigger the event responsible for this formatting, it works perfectly. However, as soon as I trigger it again, I get the error : **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' to type 'Automatisation.DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx'.'**

Here's my code :

```
        private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
                    {


            void test()
            {
                if(dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText is "Donnee1")
                {
                    var cell =(DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx)dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                    cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
                }
            }

            test();
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `if (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "Donnee1" && dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is Automatisation.DataGridViewTextBoxCellEx cell) { cell.ColumnSpan = 2; }`

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Although now I'm dealing with formatting overriding XD, which I'll try to figure out by myself